# Will the Remove action in Failover Cluster Manager 2012 R2 result in lost data on my LUN?

Tags: failovercluster, diskmanagement, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

The most specific answer I've come across for Removing an Offline and Available Storage cluster disk in Failover Cluster Manager 2012 R2 is on this site.  It's about 2yrs old.  I'm new to HyperV and am seeking confirmation to my question in the title of this post. I inadvertently added production storage to my new hyper-v cluster and want to get it off my cluster before any damage is done. Can I simply right-click the cluster disk and Remove to take it off the cluster while retaining the data in the LUN for its rightful owners?
Thank you all in advance for your response.

Best regards,
blujan

Comment: `Can I simply right-click the cluster disk and Remove to take it off the cluster while retaining the data in the LUN for its rightful owners?` - Yes

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I just needed that clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I simply right-click the cluster disk and Remove to take it off
>   the cluster while retaining the data in the LUN for its rightful
>   owners?

**Yes you can**, removing a disk from Cluster does not delete data.

**However...**

The moment your disk is no longer under cluster control, the disk is still presented to all hosts of the cluster. This is **dangerous** (for your data). Potentially if the disk comes "**online**" (in Disk Management) **in more than one** cluster node, you will end up with **data corruption**

You **must** ensure that this disk is only **presented to ONE host only** to prevent this corruption.

HTH